# PostgreSQL Unique Index performance

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a script that does some webscraping for news and then uploads the info I scrape into a PostgreSQL DB in RDS. My question is regarding the preferred method for ensuring that the same news article is not recorded more than once.

Each time I scrape, the web scraper returns 40 news articles. I have it set so that each article + headline is added to a table where the headline column has a UNIQUE key constraint. So I have 2 options in order to make sure that each article is only recorded once:

1. Use a simple try and except to try to insert every article + headline into the table -- error is returned if the headline already exists but it is ignored.
2. Or, I can query for the 40 most recently added articles in the database, compare their headlines to the ones I pulled, and then only insert those that aren't already in the database.

My question is: which one would be better performance-wise? My guess is that with a low number of articles number 1 would be better but as the number of articles increases it would be better to use number 2, is that correct?

Comment: I'd suspect (1) will always be fastest; assuming a btree index, the db will "know" where to put the new article in the index, so if there is already an entry at that location it will reject the insert.  So the cost of checking is independent of the number of index entries.  But someone who knows more about postgres should confirm this.

Comment: Most newspaper CMSses generate Stable URLs, containing an article number.Sometimes a part of the publishing date is also present. The article id can be assumed to be unique. Try to extract it from the url or the article body, and you have your unique key.

Comment: My problem is not getting the a unique value for each article my problem is making sure that unique value is not already in the database.

Comment: Then you either do an "upsert" operation, or just the plain old `insert into y select * from x where not exists (select 1 from y y2 where y2.a = x.a ...)`

Comment: "I can query for the 40 most recently added articles in the database" Why would the conflict be only in the 40 most recent articles?  It seems like that should be where the conflict is least likely to occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- create a temp table, identical to the *target* table
- put the articles you scraped into this temp
- [remove duplicates from this temp]
- insert the records from the temp table into the actual table, **but only the records that dont yet exist**

Below fragment from my twitter scraper:

---

```
    ins2 = """INSERT INTO tweets(id,sucker_id,created_at,user_id
            ,in_reply_to_id,is_reply_to_me,is_retweet,body)
     SELECT tt.id,tt.sucker_id,tt.created_at,tt.user_id
         ,tt.in_reply_to_id,is_reply_to_me,is_retweet,tt.body
     FROM tt_tweets tt
     WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM tweets nx where nx.id = tt.id)
       ;"""
```

---

And: tweets have a numerical id, which makes dedupping very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Identifying the duplicates locally to the scraper will be faster than making a round-trip to the database to do so, provided it isn't done in a dumb way.  But the difference is very unlikely to be meaningful, compared to the overhead of doing the scraping in the first place.

But if the scraper has a limited memory for headlines, you will need to have a catch-and-ignore capability anyway.